# MIPI display detection

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I'm working on a project that is utilising a Qualcomm Open-q 2500 SOM running a APQ8909W (arm based) processor. The SOM has a 4-lane MIPI D-PHY interface which can run a display at 720P (60Hz). We are trying to connect a new display that isn't already defined in the DT.

Can someone please explain to me how the system knows which display it is currently connected and what part of the system is responisble for detection of the display?
How does the system know what hardware definition in the DT (assuming it's defined already) to use?

Comment: We have a similar project to connect a MIPI display to an Android system and the lack of technical documentation about how to do this has been disappointing, and like you we are struggling to solve this and looking for similar direction.